# Individuals vanish from the IndividualsByClass List after editing them

Tags: protege

I have a class `Person` and want to create an individual for that class as an instance of that class. Adding that individual by giving the name `PeterStrotmann` for it is working fine and the individual is visible in the instances list.

Then I want to give it some attributes by editing it. After doing so with e.g. `Person and (has exactly 1 Geschlecht)`, `PeterStrotmann` is deleted from the instances list and not accessible anymore. On the other side, trying to create a new individual `PeterStrotmann` ends up in the error message 'Entity already exists'.

Answer (score 1):

Forget that silly question. What I did was editing the `Person` class while trying to edit the individual. After editing the `Person` class it wasn't the same anymore thus not finding the individual under the instances list of `Person`.